# Gulp useref is changing src path but not generating Javascript file

Tags: gulp, gulp-useref

I can't for the life of me make this output the Javascript file.

HTML:

```
<!-- build:js  scripts/combined.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src = "src/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "src/vendor/angular.1.4.8.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Gulp:

```
var useref = require('gulp-useref');

gulp.task('useref',function(){
    return gulp.src('./*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

OUTPUT:

```
<script src="scripts/combined.js"></script>
```

But literally, zero Javascript files. So weird. Any thoughts, folks?

Doesn't seem to matter how I write the path to the gulp.src, whether ('*.html') or ('./*.html') or even ('index.html'), the <src> tag gets converted fine, but there's not JS files.

Comment: Maybe @gisek http://stackoverflow.com/users/672018/gisek you have some insight?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the issue was with the whitespace around the 'src =' attributes:

this fails:

```
<!-- build:js  scripts/combined.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src = "src/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "src/vendor/angular.1.4.8.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

this works:

```
<!-- build:js  scripts/combined.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/vendor/angular.1.4.8.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```